# NDK android start

Tags: android, android-ndk

If I am good in C/C++ language, Java, and android SDK.
And I need to start in develop android using NDK. How can I start? What knowledge do I need ?
What reference do I read more from it about NDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found these links very useful when i started NDK.

1) http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-androidndk/os-androidndk-pdf.pdf

2) http://mindtherobot.com/blog/452/android-beginners-ndk-setup-step-by-step/      ==>      good link to start with Android NDK